# How to fix website loading issue in Safari on secure connection (SSL)

Tags: browser, https, safari, windows-10, ssl-certificate

Website is not loading on Safari browser with SSL. Site is running on https (SSL) layer. Please refer attached screenshot to know more.

[click here to see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EepFx.png)

P.S. I am using Windows 10 & SSL purchased from Godaddy

Answer (score 0):

Safari refuses to connect to servers that don't match the minimum security requirements defined by Apple.

For [example](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204932) and [example](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204937).

It will be necessary to contact the administrator of the server to be compliant with the standards or you can try a different browser (try IE, it never complains).